# Running parallel kubernetes jobs in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running **perfomance tests** on Jenkins. Test that may **include multiple instances of the same container** to generate necessary load. I can't hardcode number of instances as it varies based on params for tests.
I've tried to use the following code:

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
  stage('Running Jmeter') {
    agent {
      kubernetes {
          label "jmeter_tests_executor"
          yaml '''
          apiVersion: batch/v1
          kind: Job
          metadata:
            name: jmeter
            namespace: jenkins
          spec:
            parallelism: 2 
            backoffLimit: 1 
            ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
          ...
```

But it doesn't work. It's hanging on pod scheduling(jobs works ok if you apply this manifest directly on kubernetes cluster without Jenkins).
If someone had experience with it, please share your workarounds or ideas how to implement this idea.

Comment: Please add information more about your setup and configuration. It looks like there is no support in jenkins kubernetes plugin for Jobs instead you should use podTemplate

Comment: What Information do you need?
This is Jenkins in Kuberntes cluster. Every agent is a separate pod connected over jnlp.  
This is Declarative Jenkins Pipeline.  
Job runs performance test tool with some params that currently included in kuberntes job manifest.  
Going to try with podTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this

```
stage("RUN LOAD TEST") {
    steps {
        script {
            //params.each creates an array of stages
            paramsToTest.each {param -> 
                load["load test"] = {
                    stage("Executing run ${param}") {
                        agent {
                            kubernetes {
                                label "jmeter_tests_executor"
                                yaml '''
                                apiVersion: batch/v1
                                kind: Job
                                metadata:
                                name: jmeter
                                namespace: jenkins
                                spec:
                                parallelism: 2 
                                backoffLimit: 1 
                                ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
                                ...
                                '''
                            }    
                        }
                        steps {
                            <EXECUTE LOAD TEST COMMAND>
                        }
                    }
                }
                parallel(load) //actually executes the parallel stages
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What this does is use an array of something and then generates stages based on that array. The agent params in the stage should tell Jenkins to create a new pod with each execution in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for advice, going to try it on Monday.

Comment: Do you use ```container(name: 'X', shell: '/bin/sh'){}``` to execute commands in the pipeline for the job?

Comment: I don't. I'm not familiar with the syntax in your comment because I use the EC2 plugin for my Jenkins agents, but what the code snippet does is the following (assuming the behavior in K8s is the same).

Creates an array of stages from another array. Then uses the `parallel()` syntax to execute your array of stages simultaneously. This **should** create a pods for each execution where a pod isn't already available.